# Update custom field from other custom fields values

Tags: php, function, woocommerce, custom-fields

i need to update the product price based on values from some custom fields

this is how i’ve build and saving the custom fields, at the end i’m trying to update _regular_price based on the values of the customs fields when i save, update, publish the product but nothing is happening, what am i missing?

all code goes into function.php for now

```
//BUILD AND SAVE FIELDS
// Display Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

  global $woocommerce, $post;

  echo '<div class="options_group">';

// Product URL
woocommerce_wp_checkbox( 
array( 
    'label' => __('Product URL', 'woocommerce' ), 
    $post_id = $_GET['post'],
    $produrl = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'productOriginalUrl', true),
    'description'   => '<a href="' . $produrl . '" class="button button-primary button-large" target="_blank">' . __('View Product', 'woocommerce') . '</a>',
    )
);

    // Number Field
woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array( 
        'id'                => '_price_usd', 
        'label'             => __( 'Price in USD', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'placeholder'       => '', 
        'description'       => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'              => 'number', 
        'custom_attributes' => array(
                'step'  => 'any',
                'min'   => '0'
            ) 
    )
);
woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array( 
        'id'                => '_price_tax', 
        'label'             => __( 'TAX', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'placeholder'       => '', 
        'description'       => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'              => 'number', 
        'custom_attributes' => array(
                'step'  => 'any',
                'min'   => '0'
            ) 
    )

);
woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array( 
        'id'                => '_price_shipping', 
        'label'             => __( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'placeholder'       => '', 
        'description'       => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'              => 'number', 
        'custom_attributes' => array(
                'step'  => 'any',
                'min'   => '0'
            ) 
    )

);

// Select
woocommerce_wp_select( 
array( 
    'id'      => '_shipping_weight', 
    'label'   => __( 'Shipping Weight', 'woocommerce' ), 
    'options' => array(
        '3.75'   => __( 'Less Than 0.5 KG', 'woocommerce' ),
        '7.5'   => __( '0.5 KG', 'woocommerce' ),
        '15' => __( '1 KG', 'woocommerce' )
        )
    )
);

// Hidden field
woocommerce_wp_hidden_input(
array( 
    'id'    => '_usd_rate', 
    'value' => '18'
    )
);
    echo '</div>';
};

// Save Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){

    // Number Field
    $woo_price_usd = $_POST['_price_usd'];
    if( !empty( $woo_price_usd ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price_usd', esc_attr( $woo_price_usd ) );

    $woo_price_tax = $_POST['_price_tax'];
    if( !empty( $woo_price_tax ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price_tax', esc_attr( $woo_price_tax ) );

    $woo_price_shipping = $_POST['_price_shipping'];
    if( !empty( $woo_price_shipping ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price_shipping', esc_attr( $woo_price_shipping ) );

    // Select
    $woo_shipping_weight = $_POST['_shipping_weight'];
    if( !empty( $woo_shipping_weight ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_shipping_weight', esc_attr( $woo_shipping_weight ) );

    // Hidden Field
    $woo_usd_rate = $_POST['_usd_rate'];
    if( !empty( $woo_usd_rate ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_usd_rate', esc_attr( $woo_usd_rate ) );

}

//UPDATE PRICE REGULAR
function wpa104760_default_price( $post_id, $post ) {


    if ( isset( $_POST['_regular_price'] )) {
$post_id = $_GET['post'];
        $woo_price_usd = get_post_meta($post_id, '_price_usd', true);
        $woo_price_tax = get_post_meta($post_id, '_price_tax', true);
        $woo_price_shipping = get_post_meta($post_id, '_price_shipping', true);
        $woo_shipping_weight = get_post_meta($post_id, '_shipping_weight', true);
        $woo_usd_rate = get_post_meta($post_id, '_usd_rate', true);

$woo_new_product_price = (($woo_price_usd + (($woo_price_usd*$woo_price_tax)/100) + $woo_price_shipping + $woo_shipping_weight) * $woo_usd_rate );

update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', $woo_new_product_price );
        }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wpa104760_default_price' );
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer was simple,

it needed a filter to update the _regular_price and the _sale_price

```
//price new

function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
global $post;
$new_total = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_total_egp', true);
$price = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_regular_price', true);
$sale_price = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sale_price', true);
$now_price = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_price', true);

if($price != 0 ){
update_post_meta($post->ID, '_regular_price', $new_total);
update_post_meta($post->ID, '_sale_price', $new_total);
update_post_meta($post->ID, '_price', $new_total);
return $price;
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
```